# Is there a simple way to get the number of years and days between 2 dates?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a string representing a birth date I want to know how old the person is in years and days.

> **e.g:** birth = 07/04/1994  (month/days/years)
>
> So the person is 25y 78d old

But so far, using `datetime` when I do substraction between dates the result it as number of days. And because of leap years I can never be sure of the exact number of days.

```py
In [1]:
from datetime import date, datetime
today = date.today()

birth = '10/21/1996'
birth_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.strptime(birth, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%m-%d').date()
delta = today - birth_date
print(delta.days)

Out [1]:
8369
```

Comment: No. A year is not a well defined time period.

Comment: I think, maybe [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) will be able to do that. Not too sure

Comment: yours is already quite simple!

Comment: @schwobaseggl, a year is *very* well defined (at least on the Gregorian calendar). It may not be easy to turn a day count into an exact `y/d` set but that's only because you don't know the start (or end) date. Once you know that, you can get the exact `y/d` values.

Comment: @paxdiablo a year may be well defined, its general length is not. Of those 54 years you count in your solution, some are longer than the others. There is a reason why `timedelta` does not accept keywords `months` or `years`. The second-exact meaning of the phrase "I am exactly 54 years old" depends on the moment of the utterance.

Comment: I will happily agree that the length of an arbitrary year ("a year") is not well defined (I *think* that's what you're trying to get across) but the length of a specific year (like "2007") is exactly defined. That's why I mentioned that the dates were important. Provided you specify the ground rules (like your age-in-years increases at the start of your birthday and remains consistent until start of your next birthday, and your extra-age-in-days resets to zero on birthday and ticks over each midnight), it's quite easy to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as simple as a *built-in* Python function, but certainly doable using the following logic:

1. Construct a date based on the current year minus one, but the birth month and day. Call this `lastYearBirthday`. Also construct a date based on the current year but the birth month and day. Call this `currYearBirthday`.
2. If `currYearBirthday` is after `today` (the birthday is yet to occur this year), the number of full years can be obtained by subtracting `year(birthdate)` from `year(lastYearBirthday)`. The number of days over and above (days since last birthday) that is obtained with `(today - lastYearBirthday).days`.
3. Otherwise this years birthday has already happened (or is happening today) and the number of full years can therefore be obtained by subtracting `year(birthdate)` from `year(currYearBirthday)` - the number of days over that is obtained with `(today - currYearBirthday).days`.

Turning that into a Python function you can use easily, we get:

```
from datetime import date

# Functions to return tuple of (fullYears, extraDays) for
# a given birth date.

def ageInYearsAndDays(birthDate):
    # Create relevant dates to ease task.

    today = date.today()
    lastYearBirthday = date(today.year - 1, birthDate.month, birthDate.day)
    currYearBirthday = date(today.year, birthDate.month, birthDate.day)

    # Work out years and days based on whether this years
    # birthday has happened. Basic idea is that years can
    # be calculated as difference between birth year and
    # year of most recent birthday. Days is the number of
    # days between most recent birthday and today.

    if currYearBirthday > today:
        years = lastYearBirthday.year - birthDate.year
        days = (today - lastYearBirthday).days
    else:
        years = currYearBirthday.year - birthDate.year
        days = (today - currYearBirthday).days

    return (years, days)
```

And some test code shows my *own* precarious position on this mortal coil:

```
(years, days) = ageInYearsAndDays(date(1965, 2, 2))
print(years, "years and", days, "days")
```

The output being (on the day this answer was posted) a rather depressing:

```
54 years and 230 days
```

:-)

Note that I just constructed my birthdate from year, month and day directly. Since you *already* know how to turn a string into one of those (as per your question), I didn't bother using that method.

Answer (score 0):

A user built this following code for another answer on stack that captures the leap year logic.  With that said, you will need to refactor to fit your needs...

```
#Calculate the Days between Two Date

daysOfMonths = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def isLeapYear(year):

    # Pseudo code for this algorithm is found at
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm
    ## if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common Year)
    #else if (year is not divisable by 100) then (ut us a leap year)
    #else if (year is not disible by 400) then (it is a common year)
    #else(it is aleap year)
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0

def Count_Days(year1, month1, day1):
    if month1 ==2:
        if isLeapYear(year1):
            if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]+1:
                return year1, month1, day1+1
            else:
                if month1 ==12:
                    return year1+1,1,1
                else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1
        else: 
            if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]:
                return year1, month1, day1+1
            else:
                if month1 ==12:
                    return year1+1,1,1
                else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1
    else:
        if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]:
             return year1, month1, day1+1
        else:
            if month1 ==12:
                return year1+1,1,1
            else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1


def daysBetweenDates(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2,end_day):

    if y1 > y2:
        m1,m2 = m2,m1
        y1,y2 = y2,y1
        d1,d2 = d2,d1
    days=0
    while(not(m1==m2 and y1==y2 and d1==d2)):
        y1,m1,d1 = Count_Days(y1,m1,d1)
        days+=1
    if end_day:
        days+=1
    return days


# Test Case

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28,False), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1,False), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30,False), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8,False), 585 ),
                  ((1994,5,15,2019,8,31,False), 9239),
                  ((1999,3,24,2018,2,4,False), 6892),
                  ((1999,6,24,2018,8,4,False),6981),
                  ((1995,5,24,2018,12,15,False),8606),
                  ((1994,8,24,2019,12,15,True),9245),
                  ((2019,12,15,1994,8,24,True),9245),
                  ((2019,5,15,1994,10,24,True),8970),
                  ((1994,11,24,2019,8,15,True),9031)]

    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

[How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: Doesn't this simply provide what you get from `(date - date).days` as per the OP's question? I think they wanted an accurate way to turn that into years and days.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of exercises from the good old days on stack overflow in September. This should illustrate you the logic. Note that a year is leap only when is perfectly divided by 4, 100 or 400. You can then make use of datetime attributes to have fun.

```
from datetime import date, datetime
today = date.today()

birth = '10/21/1996'
birth_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.strptime(
    birth, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
delta = today - birth_date

days = delta.days
year_counter = 0
if today.day >= birth_date.day and today.month >= birth_date.month:
    full_years = today.year
else:
    full_years = today.year - 1

for year in range(1996, full_years):
    if (year % 4) == 0 or (year % 100) == 0 or (year % 400) == 0:
        days -= 366
        year_counter += 1
    else:
        days -= 365
        year_counter += 1

print("years: " + str(year_counter) + "\ndays: " + str(days))
```

Obviously there are more Pythonic way to write it, but I suppose you wanted some readability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not a logic test for university as you think. Just a personnal project where I don't want to "waste time" on this. I was looking for a package with built in functions. 

I think `Pendulum` might be the good one

Comment: My bad. Probably [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) is more useful then. Look into [relative delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071561/python-difference-in-years-between-a-datetime-now-and-a-series-filled-up-with)